# How to ignore one factor when determining ylim with faceted plot

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

In the following (nonsensical) example, I would like to plot both y1 and y2 curves, but have the ylim determined according to the y1 curve, ignoring y2.

Here's the example:

```
library(ggplot2)

curves <- data.frame(expand.grid(seq(-2,2,0.1), c(2,4), c(1,2)))
names(curves) <- c("x","p","c")

curves$y1 <- splat(function(x,p,c, ...) c * p * exp(- x^p))(curves)
curves$y2 <- splat(function(x,p,c, ...) c + x * p)(curves)
curves <- melt.data.frame(curves, id.vars=1:3)

ggplot(curves, aes(x, value, color = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(p ~ c, scales="free_y")
```

I would like the first row to have ylim(0,4) and the second row to have ylim(0,8). Any thoughts? Preferably on how to have ggplot determine the correct limits, rather than entering them manually?

Comment: Where do 4 and 8 come from? `max(curves$value[curves$p == 2]) [1] 6` and `max(curves$value[curves$p == 4]) [1] 10`

Comment: Ah I forgot to edit the entry after I'd made a change in my R code. y1 should be defined as the function c * p * exp(- x^p). Edited above.

Comment: Not currently easy, but I'm hoping to make it possible for a layer not to effect position scales in a future version.

Answer (score 2):

The following works, although it feels clumsy.  No doubt you can improve on this.

My workaround is to delete values from the data.frame that you don't want to include in the plot:

```
curves <- subset(curves, !(curves$p==2 & (curves$value>4 | curves$value<0)))
curves <- subset(curves, !(curves$p==4 & (curves$value>8 | curves$value<0)))

ggplot(curves, aes(x, value, color = variable)) +
        geom_line() +
        facet_grid(p ~ c, scales="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: +1, this is how I was going to suggest going about the problem. I still don't quite get why 4 and 8 are the "correct" limits though...

Answer (score 1):

If you end with this rather verbose code

```
ylimits <- c(  floor(min(curves$value[curves$variable == "y1"])),
             ceiling(max(curves$value[curves$variable == "y1"])) )

ggplot(curves, aes(x, value, color = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(p ~ c, scales = "free_y") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = ylimits[1]:ylimits[2]) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = ylimits)
```

you get this,

[image: Scale decided by red curves]

which bases the y-axis scale on the y1 curve (though not on your 4 and 8).